# How to show repeated result on LCD while button is pressing

Tags: arduino-nano, lcd, button, input

my results are here.
0 press--"a"
1st press--"b"
2nd press--"c"
3rd press-- still showing "c"
When button pressed 3rd time, It must be repeated to show "a" again. How can I repeat above 3 results to LCD?

```cpp
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>    
#include <ezButton.h>     
ezButton button(7);  
int count;      
int count1;  
const float rs = 1, en = 2, d4 = 3, d5 = 4, d6 = 5, d7 = 6;  
LiquidCrystal lcd(rs, en, d4, d5, d6, d7);   
void setup() {  
  button.setDebounceTime(50); // set debounce time to 50 milliseconds   
  button.setCountMode(COUNT_FALLING);   
  lcd.begin(16, 1);     
}                     
void loop() {            
  int count = button.getCount();                 
  button.loop();               
  count1 = constrain(count, 0, 2);                 
  if(count1 == 0){                
  lcd.print("a");                 
  }               
  if(count1 == 1){             
  lcd.print("b");             
  }              
  if(count1 == 2){              
  lcd.print("c");           
  }            
  delay(500);              
  lcd.clear();                
}
```

Comment: investigate the remainder operator `%`

Comment: use `button.resetCount();`

Comment: The ezButton counter will keep counting up every time you release the button. `count` will be 3, then 4, 5, etc. But [constrain](https://reference.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/math/constrain/) will keep `count1` stuck at 2. You could use `button.resetCount();` when you print `c` to start over. Or use `count1 = count % 3` like jsotola suggested.